# How to establish database(SQL) Connection using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, database

I want to establish a database connection for receiving the details of the customers using C#. I am using sql-server 2008 along with visual studio 2010.....

Here is this code:

```
<asp:Textbox id="TxtBox1" runat="server" />
<asp:Textbox id="TxtBox2" runat="server" />
<asp:Button id="Button1" runat="server" Onclick="Button1_Click" />
```

and the codebehind:

```
protected void Button1_Click(Object sender,EventArgs e)
{
string Text1=TextBox1.Text;
string Text2=TextBox2.Text;
string connectionString="Data Source=servername;InitialCatalog=DataBaseNameUserID=sa;  Password=YourPassword;"

SqlConnection sqlConnection=new SqlConnection(connectionString);

string insertStatement="INSERT INTO TableName(column1,column2) VALUES Txtb1+","+Txtb2";

SqlCommand sqlCommand=new SqlCommand(insertStatement,sqlConnection);

try
{
sqlConnection.Open();
sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

}
finally
{
sqlConnection.Close();
}


}
```

I have created the data.mdf file in it i have created table containing fields but i am getting Connection has not established error can any one help me to resolve my problem???

Comment: Don't use the sa account in applications! This code is incredibly vulnerable to a sql injection attack, not to mention the fact that the connection string is malformed, and the `inserStatment` line will not compile.

Comment: Sorry..,I didn't get you could you please express me about sa???

Comment: You are using the administrator account. The one that has full access to the sql server. All you need is an account with write access to the one table. Always use the minimum permissions possible.

Comment: Proper research is a must: http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: kk if you don't mind can you post the modified code by taking small example taking the two text fields and after clicking the submit button the data will be stored into the database(i'm using visual studio 2010 and sql server 2008 along with it based on my requirement can you please post the alternate code)

Answer (score 5):

This connection string is wrong.

```
string connectionString="Data Source=servername;InitialCatalog=DataBaseNameUserID=sa;" + 
                        "Password=YourPassword;"
```

should be

```
string connectionString="Data Source=servername;InitialCatalog=DataBaseName; UserID=sa;" + 
                        "Password=YourPassword;"
```

However, NEVER use the sa user in your applications. Create a new user with Management Studio or better use Integrated Security.

Also the remainder of your code should be written in this way

```
using(SqlConnection sqlConnection=new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
     string insertStatement="INSERT INTO TableName(column1,column2) VALUES (@col1, @col2)";
     SqlCommand sqlCommand=new SqlCommand(insertStatement,sqlConnection);
     sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col1", Text1);
     sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col2", Text2);
     sqlConnection.Open();
     sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

- Use the [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) to correctly close and dispose your
  SqlConnection
- Use [parametrized query](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/puranindia/parameterized-query-and-sql-injection-attacks/) in your sql commands to avoid parsing problems
  an [Sql Injection Attacks](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html)

Comment: Beat me to the re-write too.  I always enclose the SqlCommand in a using block as well.

Comment: Yes, should be done also on SqlCommand, but it is on the SqlConnection that the problem is big

Comment: after clicking the submit button based on the above given code there is no response for that code

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean 'there is no response'? The code is not executed?, the record is not written to the database? do you expect any visual feedback of code execution? Please explain

Answer (score 0):

This code does not compile.  You need to add a semicolon to this line:

```
string connectionString="Data Source=servername;InitialCatalog=DataBaseNameUserID=sa;  Password=YourPassword;"
```

Like so:

```
string connectionString="Data Source=servername;InitialCatalog=DataBaseNameUserID=sa;  Password=YourPassword;";
```

You also need to change this line:

```
string insertStatement="INSERT INTO TableName(column1,column2) VALUES Txtb1+","+Txtb2";
```

To this:

```
string insertStatement = "INSERT INTO TableName(column1,column2) VALUES " + Text1 + ", " + Text2;
```

Answer (score 0):

The connection string itself may be the issue, windows has an easy way to create a valid connection string that you can test and then just copy it to your app. I wrote about it a couple of months ago [here](http://www.megustaulises.com/2012/04/how-to-create-connection-string.html):

Tips for your app:

- As pointed by asawyer, don't use the sa account, create a login with access to the database(s) you need.
- Use the [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) statement

example:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))  
    {  
      //here you open and execute the command
    }
```

- User parameterized queries to avoid sql injection. [Here is a good article](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html).

Answer (score 0):

use the connection string as follows:

```
connectionString="Data Source=ServerAddress;Initial Catalog=DataBaseName;Integrated Security=SSPI;User ID=Domain\Username;Password=Password;"
```