# Need information on the connections for sql used in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, dataset, sqlconnection, sqldataadapter

I'm totally new to asp.net C#. I need information on how to make SQL connections.
I google it and got some of the information on connecting to database. I need the explanation such as what exactly `SqlConnection con` does and what exactly `SqlCommand cmd` means.

And the commands such as

```
con.Open()
DataSet ds = new DataSet(cmd,con)
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter()
da.Fill(ds)
con.Close()
// etc.
```

Where do i find the explanation on this commands?
Also please help me with all the commands which i would need to learn to make connections with SQL.
Could you please help me out with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Start here:  [ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e80y5yhx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: You could also look at the individual objects: [SqlConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx), [SqlDataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.aspx), and [SqlCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is a complete and simple tutorial](http://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet) about ADO.Net.

Good work!

Answer (score 0):

SqlConnection : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

SqlCommand :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Check this site : 
[Connect ASP.NET WebSite to SQL Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8014901/connect-asp-net-website-to-sql-database)

[How to establish database(SQL) Connection using c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13974308/how-to-establish-databasesql-connection-using-c)

Thanks.